# build table rows from Ajax response(Json) error: 'Invalid Character'

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, json

I'm successfully getting the response as jSon from my code behind c#. While converting jSon to table in jQuery it throwing error('Invalid Character'). here is **my code:**

```
$('#reports').click(function () {
        var pageUrl = '<%= ResolveUrl("~/Admin.aspx/SystemstatusReport")%>';
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: pageUrl,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (data) {
                var response = $.parseJSON(data);

                $(function () {
                    $.each(response, function (i, item) {
                        var $tr = $('<tr>').append(
                            $('<td>').text(item.SystemID),
                            $('<td>').text(item.SystemIP),
                            $('<td>').text(item.SystemStatus)
                        ); 
                        console.log($tr.wrap('<p>').html());
                    });
                });
            },
            error: function (data, success, error) {
                alert("Error:" + error);
            }
        });
    });
```

My **c# [WebMethod]**

```
public static string SystemstatusReport()
{
    using (OleDbConnection con=new OleDbConnection( conStr))
    {
        con.Open();
        string query = "SELECT * FROM SystemStatus";
        using (OleDbDataAdapter da=new OleDbDataAdapter( query,con))
        {
            DataSet ds=new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
            var jsonString = DataTableToJson(dt);                
            return jsonString;
        }
    }

}
```

**Edit:**

My json response:

```
[{ "SystemId": 1753259, "IP": "1855652", "SystemStatus": "online" },{ "SystemId": 1753359, "IP": "1585652", "SystemStatus": "online" }]
```

Comment: Can you console.log(data) and paste the output? It could be helpful.

Comment: Hi @Michelem I edited the question

Answer (score 0):

It should be `data.d` as shown below:

```
 var response = $.parseJSON(data.d);
```

Because C# => 3.5 serialize all JSON responses into a variable d.

You need to change your code as below:

```
$(function () {
                    $.each(response, function (i, item) {
                        var $tr = $('<tr>').append(
                            $('<td>').text(item.SystemId),
                            $('<td>').text(item.IP), 
                            $('<td>').text(item.SystemStatus)
                        ); 
                        console.log($tr.wrap('<p>').html());
                    });
                });
```

You need to give exact name as it is in Json response.

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/Rj9bR/57/

Comment: I changed that line. Now it's not showing any error. But it's not showing any results?

Comment: same result!. Can you just write an example in the same fiddle?

Comment: it is showing <td>1753259</td><td>1855652</td><td>online</td>
(index):34 <td>1753359</td><td>1585652</td><td>online</td>

Comment: plz tell what type of result you want @SarathJasrin

Comment: SytemId, SystemIP, SystemStaus these 3 are headers others are values. I want to create a table.

Comment: you need to give headers manually if ur not inserting from jquery @SarathJasrin

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88576/discussion-between-sarath-jasrin-and-neel).

Comment: can u continue the chat in chat room ?

Comment: u got solution? @SarathJasrin

Comment: Yes I want. I just copied the code from your fiddle replaced the #record_table with my table. It's returning undefined. Not the error. In the table value(one line only).

Comment: Can we continue on chat ?

Comment: chat not allowed here sorry. i mean prohibited!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zvrusnpt/2/ here it works , i have removed ajax call as it is giving correct result. if u still face problem then there is something wrong in ur ajax cal @SarathJasrin

Comment: I think i'm not getting the correct Json string. Actually I'm getting Json from  my c# code using Newtonsof.Json.

Answer (score 0):

I used JSON.parse method to get the json string. Below is my code

```
success: function (data) {
            var sam = JSON.parse(data);

            $(function () {
               var trHTML = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < sam.length; i++) {
        trHTML += '<tr><td>' + sam[i].IP + '</td><td>' + sam[i].SystemID + '</td><td>' + sam[i].Bay + '</td></tr>';
    }$('#records_table').append(trHTML);
                });
            });
```

And also I forgot to mention index of the JSON object.